# restarting Application Pool every specific duration asp.net. IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, application-pool

my application pool gets stopped every now and then coz of some problem in code or something wrong on the page, so i want to restart the application pool every 5 mins, so that i dont have to open IIS and restart it everytime it gets stopped. is there any way i can start application pool if it stops.

Comment: Restarting IIS is like using an atomic bomb to hammer a nail. Perhaps you could tell us more about your problem?

Comment: i dont want to restart IIS instead i want to restart application pool.

Comment: Though @rlb.usa may be over-doing it, the premise is the same; find the solution to the _real_ problem, and don't worry about automating the band-aid. I would recommend enabling tracing/logging and see if you can't trace the exact point where the problem occurs, not trying to work-around it.

Comment: I also would like to do the same. We inherited a project which is in ASP and we have no knowledge of ASP. The website goes down every now and then and recycling the application pool does the trick. Were you able to do this?